# Stop changing status bar in iOS 13

Tags: swift, statusbar, ios13

I have already a light and dark theme in my app. I also supported iOS 13 dark mode, the problem is, even when the light or dark mode of the app is selected, changing iOS theme leads to change status bar color, so when the ios dark mode is on, the status bar is invisible in the light theme in my app. 
I tried to prevent it by this block of codes, but it won't work in my case:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    switch Appearance.theme {
    case .dark:
        return .lightContent
    case .light:
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return .darkContent
        } else {
            return .default
        }
    case .apple:
        return .default
    }
}
```

I added it in he split view controller, I also add it in each controller but nothing changes. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?
I aslo have same problem for `UITabbar` and `UISegmentedControl`

Somehow I should say that when the light and dark mode in my app is selected, changing iOS theme should effect in the app element (status bar, tabbar, UISegmentedControl)

Many Thanks

Comment: Check if you're overriding it in the Info.plist

Comment: No I didn't change anything in Info.plist

Comment: Having the same issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` to force controllers to adopt a specific style in `iOS13`.

To solve your problem, your code should be like that:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    switch Appearance.theme {
    case .dark:
        return .lightContent
    case .light:
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return .darkContent
        } else {
            return .default
        }
    case .apple:
        return .default
    }
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
         switch Appearance.theme {
         case .dark:
             overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
         case .light:
             overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
         case .apple:
             overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .unspecified
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: There is no Appearance.theme

Comment: Appearance.theme is part of @Robert project.